# Angular 6: not able to route components(root to child) on creating different module

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new to angular and having some issue in defining angular child routes. I don't know what mistake i am doing. On creating different module for the child components, an issue is generated while defining routes.

> `Template parse errors:
>   'app-sidebar' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

#### Error:

```html
  <h1>Welcome Admin!!</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>[ERROR ->]<app-sidebar></app-sidebar></li>
    <li><router-outlet></router-outlet></li>
    </ul>`
```

---

here is the **`structure`** of the project

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtyOY.png)

---

here is the **`main module`**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { MainpageComponent } from './mainpage/mainpage.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: MainpageComponent
    },
     {
      path: 'admin',
      component: AdminComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MainpageComponent,
    AdminComponent,  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AdminModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

here is the **`admin module`**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { BookingComponent } from './booking/booking.component';

const adminRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'booking',
        component: BookingComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes),
  ],
  declarations: [  
    SidebarComponent,
    BookingComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

---

here is the html code in **`admin.component.html`** that is having issue

```html
<div class="admin-header">
    <h1>Welcome Admin!!</h1>
    <ul>
    <li><app-sidebar></app-sidebar></li>
    <li><router-outlet></router-outlet></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Why `sidebar component` route is not working?

Comment: Export side-bar component in its declaring modules's `exports: [..., SidebarComponent]`

Comment: it is working but separately, not as a child of app module, `http://localhost:4200/admin/` and `http://localhost:4200/booking` i want as `http://localhost:4200/admin/booking`.

Comment: If you need as you mentioned in the above comment, you need to create a parent route "admin" and then the child routes "admin/booking", "admin/something-else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which you import your modules is also important. You need to import `AdminModule` after `RouterModule.forRoot()`, then define a route in the AdminModule to load the SideBarComponent.

Comment: Yes i had defined it. still parent to child module is not working.

Comment: You also need to export the component from the module if you want to use it in another module. For you scenario, please add the `SidebarComponent` to the `exports` array of the `AdminModule`.

Comment: yes now sidebar component is working but it is working separately, not as a child of app module, `http://localhost:4200/admin/` and `http://localhost:4200/ booking` i want as `http://localhost:4200/admin/booking`.

Comment: You can create the `AdminModule` as a lazyloaded module and use children in routing.  The angular.io docs explains it best.